# What's the correct code to use View like a redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

One of the View methods on the Controller class (in System.Web.Mvc) allows you pass a model to a different view. However, it does not update the url to the name of the new view because this method works more like Server.Tranfer than Response.Redirect. The point is that this behaviour can be confusing to anyone picking-up MVC. So, after the View method has been called, I would like the url path to be rewritten to reflect the name of the new view. I have tried the following, which does not work, on a class that implements the Controller class:

```
public ViewResult ViewAsRedirect(string viewName, object model)
{
    var baseView = base.View(viewName, model);

    ControllerContext.HttpContext.RewritePath(baseView.ViewName);

    return baseView;
}
```

What's the correct code to implement what I have described?

**EDIT**

Any RedirectToAction method does not allow you to send you model to another action. There is a dirty workaround where you store it in TempData before you exit one action and retrieve it at the beginning of another action. I don't want to use this pattern. This is why I am using View(...) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot "update the URL" (i.e. redirect) *and* return content.

If you want the new URL to show the same content as you anticipated, then you'll need to (temporarily) store the results and include an identifier for the resource that you wish to display on the redirected URL.

There you can pull the resource in from the controller for the redirected URL again, and display it on the appropriate view.

So if you POST your `object model` to `/Foo/Create`, you can for example store `model` in a database, which yields an ID: `42`. Then you can [redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to `/Foo/View/42`, and display it.

If you can explain what you are actually trying to do, a more concrete answer can be given.

Answer (score 1):

`RedirectToAction` is very intuitive in my opinion... you should use one of the redirecting methods of MVC controller: `Redirect(url)`, `RedirectToAction(acion)`, `RedirectToAction(acion, controller)`, and so on.

**example**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Redirect()
    {
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If your action needs to collect tons of data to pass to the view, you could redirect very early, by detecting the condition of redirection, and loading all the data inside the other action, based on simple route data such as database IDs, or simple strigs or numbers.

**== OR ==**

You can render javascript code to change the URL in the client side, when the page loads: [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)
This works only in very recent browsers (current date nov/2013).

Comment: Sorry, redirect doesn't allow you to send a model to another action. Hence, that's why I am using View.

Comment: Unless your model is huge, you can pass it as route values object.

Comment: I want to do this everywhere. It's a large application and I don't fancy hand-coding each property as route values, especially when some of those properties are complex.

Comment: You can do this in client side, but support not all browsers support it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: Well that means not all my customers can use the application. So, that's a none starter.